# jQuery load after submit, with if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement, load, submit

My problem: document's not loading nsfw.html(don't judge me!) from else if statement after clicking submit button:
Jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/tKeYf/](http://jsfiddle.net/tKeYf/)
But I guess it's not working there, so i uploaded it to my host: [here](http://arnolds.co.nf/this)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="Age" maxlength="3" size="3" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Okay">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // verification
    $('title').html('jQuery`s working!');
    // submit
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
        var a = $('input[type=text]').val();
        if (a == '') {
            alert('Enter Your Age!');
        } else if (a < 18) {
            alert('You Shall Not Pass!');
        } else if (a >= 18) {
            alert('Welcome Aboard!');

            // Here's the problem!
            $('html').load('nsfw.html');
        } else {
            alert('Age Is A Number!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Fairly certain you can't load an entire HTML page into another with `load()` (the markup would be invalid). Is there a reason you're not just redirecting?

Comment: If you don't want to redirect to "nsfw.html", set this part of code in jquery `$('body').load('nsfw.html');`, then on "nsfw.html" remove html, head and body tags, leave just content of body. In that case, all CSS of "nsfw.html" must be inside landing page.

Comment: It doesn't work Miljan Puzovič!

Comment: Just one side note - if you do this via jQuery, users will see in source code link to "nsfw.html" and avoid age validation. Better solution is to use PHP.

Comment: I know, but kids or regular user won't know how to use that blank 'nsfw.html'.

Comment: jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the document retrieved by `load()`, and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or the entire `<head>`, removing them from the inserted markup. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't change nothing, but I found this helpful, but I suppose, that window.close() wont work: `else if (a >= 18) {

                    alert('Welcome Aboard!');

                    window.close();

                    window.open('nsfw.html')

                }`